# Selenium StaleElementReferenceException explicit wait

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my Selenium test code I have a few lines that

1. Clicks a check box
2. Selects an item from a select box
3. Clicks a buttom to submit a form

Here is the code

```
WebElement selectAllElement = driver.findElement(By.id("filterForm:selectAll"));
if (selectAllElement.isSelected())
{
    selectAllElement.click();
}

Select selectLocation = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    .until(ExpectedConditions
    .presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("filterForm:selectLocation"))));

selectLocation.selectByVisibleText(location);

WebElement filterButton = driver.findElement(By.id("filterForm:filterButton"));
filterButton.click();
```

I was receiving a `StaleElementReferenceException` when trying to retrieve the Select element on the page, to try and get around this I added an explicit wait on this element as can be seen in the code above.

I am however still getting a `StaleElementReferenceException`

**EDIT (HTML for those elements)**

```
<form id="filterForm" name="filterForm" method="post" action="/UsersJSFMavenApplication/faces/index.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="filterForm" value="filterForm" />
<input id="filterForm:selectAll" type="checkbox" name="filterForm:selectAll" checked="checked" title="allUsers" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'filterForm:filterGrid usersForm')" />All users<table id="filterForm:filterGrid">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input id="filterForm:userName" type="text" name="filterForm:userName" disabled="disabled" /></td>
<td><select id="filterForm:selectLocation" name="filterForm:selectLocation" size="1" disabled="disabled">   <option value="Keynsham">Keynsham</option>
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="Silicon Valley">Silicon Valley</option>
</select></td>
<td><input id="filterForm:filterButton" type="submit" name="filterForm:filterButton" value="Filter" disabled="disabled" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-8198231560613594227:-8434387391056535341" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your Url..?

Comment: You can post your HTML code for those elements.

Comment: Ok I've done that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue by changing

```
Select selectLocation = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    .until(ExpectedConditions
    .presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("filterForm:selectLocation"))));
```

To

```
Select selectLocation = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    .until(ExpectedConditions
    .elementToBeClickable(By.id("filterForm:selectLocation"))));
```

Why it made a difference I don't know, perhaps someone could shed some light as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem a few weeks back. Might be a good idea to read up on what [StaleElementException](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) is first.

My problem was an asynchronous call was being made between the time of selecting an element and carrying out some action. My solution was to wrap a try catch in a while loop and attempt to click element a number of times before throwing an Exception. So like this:

```
     public static void clickElement(By by) throws Exception {
        boolean isClicked = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while(!isClicked && attempts < 5) {
            try {
                WebElement element = driver().findElement(by);
                element.click();
                isClicked = true;
            } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
                attempts++;
                System.out.println("[DEBUG] StaleElementReference exception caught, trying to locate and click element again");
            }
        }
        if(!isClicked) {
          throw new Exception("Could not click " + by + ", after 5 attempts");
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the checkbox if that check box is not selected or not enabled.

try like this:

```
  WebElement checkboxEle = driver.findElement(By.id("filterForm:selectAll"));
  if (!checkboxEle.isEnable())
   {
        checkboxEle.click();
   }

  //To Select option
 WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='filterForm:selectLocation']"));
 Select selectLocation = new Select(selectElement);

 selectLocation.selectByVisibleText("London");
```

Answer (score 0):

We usually get the stale element exception when the element is no longer attached to the DOM. So, try to refresh your page if the required element is not found.

```
 try {
    WebElement expectedStaleElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
    expectedStaleElement.click(); 
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e){
    e.toString();
    System.out.println("Trying to recover from a stale element :" +    e.getMessage());
    driver.navigate().refresh(); //refresh your web page
    WebElement expectedStaleElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));//again re- declare web element
    expectedStaleElement.click(); 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.manage().timeOuts().implicitWait(timeUnit.SECONDS,10);
```